# How should I test this behavior using PHPUnit in CakePHP 3.0 ?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, integration-testing

I have this method in BrandBehavior and I want to test it.

```
public function setCurrentBrandId(Entity $entity)
{
    if (!isset($entity->brand_id) or empty($entity->brand_id)) {
        $entity->brand_id = $this->session->read("Brand.id");
    }
}
```

I want to test if this method actually sets the BrandID. Could You give me the example how should I test this ? So far I have covered basically nothing.

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->Progress = new BrandsBehavior();
}  
public function testSetCurrentBrandId()
{

}
```

If you need anything else let me know and just so that you know that I am beginner with tests and testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, behaviors don't usually have access to session (`$this->session`) - I assume you are injecting it somewhere. In this case you can mock the session object and test against that (you can read about mocking [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)).

Second, the method signature for `\Cake\ORM\Behavior::__construct` is `Table $table, array $config = []` - this means that you need to change a bit the `setUp` method. [This](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/tests/TestCase/ORM/Behavior/TimestampBehaviorTest.php#L55-L56) should give an idea.

Third, testing is about verifying that the function/method does what you expect it to do (based on input). So for actual tests you can give it two entities (one that has `brand_id` field and other that doesn't) and `assertEquals` the new value of the `brand_id` field after calling this method

Also, a couple of tips:

- `!$entity->has('field_name')` is a shortcut for `!isset($entity->brand_id) or empty($entity->brand_id)`
- Injecting your session object into a behavior is not a good idea. While it has an obvious use, I suggest that you either inject the actual value into the behavior or (if you need the function to read from session) move this to a component.
- Instead of hardcoding `"Brand.id"` as a session key to read, consider having it as a config key

Comment: Thanks for the response Xymanek. 
Then I have some further questions. I am actually injecting the $this->session into the initialize method and I am trying to mock it inside the test method. I don't get these lines inside the test method - 
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->createMock(SomeClass::class);
I get what is SomeClass and that it should be Session, but I don't get what is class ? 
Thanks for the tips. I am using all three of them.

Comment: SomeClass::class returns the class name (with namespace) as a string

Comment: First method in my testing class is like this. 

    public function testSetCurrentBrandId()
    {
        $stub = $this->createMock(Session::class);

        $stub->method('setCurrentBrandId')
            ->willReturn(1);

        $this->assertEquals(1, $stub->setCurrentBrandId());

And this is what it returns: 
Trying to configure method "setCurrentBrandId" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static

Does this mean that I don't have access to the class which I am trying to test ??

Comment: @Speedy You are a bit confused - you are trying to mock `setCurrentBrandId()` which is not part of the session object, it belongs to the behavior. Also, if you are new to testing, PhpUnit, etc. I strongly suggest that you read some articles from Google on it.